# Wireguard setup script keeps freezing

Tags: wireguard

I'm trying to get a demo run of Wireguard by running the sample script [client.sh](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/plain/contrib/ncat-client-server/client.sh) from their website.
Every time I run the script on Fedora 35, it keeps freezing without doing anything. Finally, after about 5 minutes the script exits but no changes have been made to the network configurations of my system, and I cannot ping the virtual IP address mentioned in the [docs](https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/#demo-server) (192.168.4.1). Also, tried running client.sh default-route, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Add `set -x` at the start of the `client.sh` script and that should show where it is failing.

Comment: Btw, it's working here. Are you behind a firewall preventing outgoing connections?

Comment: I tried also disabling the firewall, but to no avail.